# setting bits at shifts using bitwise operators

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Im trying to replicate the function

```
int test(int x, int y)
 {
   int result = 0;
   int i;
   for (i = y; i <= x; i++)
   result |= 1 << i;
   return result;
  }
```

which takes two ints and sets a bit for each position between the two numbers. Assuming  0 <= x <= 31, and 0 <= y <= 31. For example (7, 5) will set 1 to 1110 0000 where a bit is set after shifting 5, 6, and 7 times.

Im trying to do the same thing but have been restricted to using only certain bitwise operators (~ & + <<). however am having difficulty finding a way that does not use a loop. The function should return 0 if y > x.

I believe I can replicate the or operator x|y using ~(~x & ~y).

and x^y using ~(~(~x & y) & ~(x & ~y));

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm

Comment: Easier to replicate if code used `unsigned test(unsigned  x, unsigned  y)` rather than `int`.  Negative values and `int` overflow are a pain.

Comment: Calling `+` a 'bitwise operator' is a little unusual.  So, the problem is that the revised function must handle a range of values for `x` and `y` (what is the maximum allowed value — 6, 7, 14, 15, 30, 31, 62, 63?) and must _not_ use a loop to do so?  Can it use conditionals?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler my apologies, the range is 0 <= x <= 31, and 0 <= y <= 31. Correct im trying to do so without looping and cannot use conditionals.

Comment: `((1u << (y+1)) + ~0u) & ~((1u << x) + ~0u)`

Comment: @Dmitri did not work for me, nor do I quite follow.

Comment: `1` shifted by `(y+1)` sets the bit for 2**(y+1), then adding `~0` (all 1's) effectively subtracts one to get all lower bits set instead.  Then do the same for `x` instead of `y+1`, invert it so only the low bits are clear, then AND the two.  Works for me as long as `y` is less than 31, or for everything if I use `~0u` instead of `((1u << (y+1)) + ~0u)` just for when `y==31`

Comment: @Dmitri this is my implementation of your method which returns 0, have I made a mistake? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3fb37154200fa6666671ce289e35a838

Comment: Looks right except for the special case when `y` is 31 or whatever the highest bit number is (if it is, just `return ~((1u << x) + ~0u);` instead).

Comment: Oh wait, I have the low number in `x` and you have it in `y`... try swapping `x` and `y`

Comment: @Dmitri ah yes that was it, my mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `-` you could do it like this:

```
int test(int x, int y)
{
    int mask1 = (1 << y) - 1;
    int mask2 = (1 << (x+1)) - 1;
    int result = mask1 ^ mask2;
    return result;
}
```

Checking for y > x is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I considered that, however both - and ^ are restricted.